# Android Activity not redrawing

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with simple android activity, it's just relative Layout. The problem is, that if I write something, cursor remains and so written text if I delete it.

[example 1](http://tajv.cz/IMG/a%20(2).png)
[example 2](http://tajv.cz/IMG/a%20(1).png)

I don't know how to fix it and don't have any other device to try if it is something with the device. (Nexus 7 2012, Android 4.4.4)

Layout:

```
<!-- options header -->            
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Options_text"
    android:text="@string/options"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"    
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="48sp"
 />  

<!-- IP address row -->     
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/IP_address_text" 
    android:layout_below="@id/Options_text"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:text="@string/ip_addr"
 />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/IP_address"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Options_text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IP_address_text"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:width="300dp"
    android:maxLength="15" />

<!-- port row --> 
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Port_text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="@string/port" 
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/IP_address_text"
    android:layout_width="150dp"/>  
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Port"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:inputType="phone" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/IP_address_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Port_text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:width="100dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Class:

```
public class Options extends Activity {

    public void fullscreen(){
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fullscreen();
        setContentView(R.layout.options);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest testing this application on another device. With what you provided, there would be no errors to cause this. If you cannot obtain another device to test your application with, you can always [set up an AVD.](https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) This would allow you to use your application on a "new" device which has not had any previous changes that would cause conflicts.

*Testing with multiple devices is always a good plan. It will allow you to discover issues. or even solutions that you may not have found otherwise.*